# input placeholder text getting cutoff

Tags: html, css, placeholder

I am creating webview wherein I am using couple of INPUT tags with placeholder text to get the user input.

However, in some devices i.e. MOTO E2 for instance, the placeholder text is getting cutoff and we can only view the top part (around 1px) of the text.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 10):

You could add `overflow: visible;` to your `input::placeholder` styles

Comment: Any explanation why this works?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that adjusting the padding inside the text field may solve your problem.

Consider this example:

```css
.custom-input {
  padding: 25px 20px 0px 10px !important;
  height: 30px !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input type="text" class="form-control custom-input" placeholder="Some Text" />
```

Post your code if this is not the case.

Answer (score -1):

In the Css for this web view I had used line height of 2px and when I removed it, the problem was solved.